# I see frequent major gc when there is lot of space in old/young gen

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I see frequent major gc when there is lot of space in old/young gen.

Only thing i see is survivor space is 100% full all the time. java vm args are as below

`-Xms2200m -Xmx2200m -XX:NewSize=600m -XX:MaxNewSize=600 -XX:SurvivorRatio=3 -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=292m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

`-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution`

Adding the link to gc logs below. please provide any guidance on what should i be looking at.

http://sdrv.ms/1fH9Bm7

Thanks

Comment: have you tried with a larger SurvivorRatio or simply use the default (32 for solaris)

Comment: survivor space configuration was added because the setting before was causing the old gen to fill up and was resulting in full gc. so that's why i had added survivor space so that the objects will remain in the young gen for longer period before promoted.

Comment: do you see old generation filling up in jvisualvm?  I did not go through all your logs.

Comment: its 60-75% full between any time but it is never full. the eden space reaches 100% and by minor collection it goes down. The big concern is why the survivor space is always 100%. And if that is causing the frequent major collections.

Comment: have you checked the gc count for the old generation in jvisualvm?  I was guessing that probably objects are being sent to old generation too fast from survivor spaces

Answer (score 1):

Survivor space 100% is generally ok (ideally it should be just little below 100%).

These two articles could you basic ideas about mechanics of generational GC and CMS

- [Understanding GC pauses in JVM, HotSpot's minor GC](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html)
- [Understanding GC pauses in JVM, HotSpot's CMS collector](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots_02.html)

Getting back to your question.

You have class unloading enabled (`XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`) this means following.
If PERM gen usage is close to its limit (say 90%), which is perfectly ok for PERM, CMS collection will be started. And if there are no classes to unload, CMS cycle will not free any space in PERM and next CMS collection will be triggers right after.

To put simple, if PERM is filled close to its capacity - concurrent collections will run non stop.